# How to create an express Application with import instead of require

Tags: typescript, express

This is what works with `require`. We instead want it to use `import`.

```
import { Request, Response, Application } from 'express';

// TODO Figure out how NOT to use require here.
const express = require('express');
var app: Application = express();

app.get('/', function (req: Request, res: Response) {
  res.send('Hello World')
});

app.listen(3000);
```

### What we have tried

Our tsconfig.json has `"esModuleInterop": true`.

#### Attempt # 1

```
import express from 'express';
```

That gives this error:

> "node_modules/@types/express/index"' has no default export.ts

#### Attempt # 2

```
import * as express from 'express';
var app = express();
```

That gives a different error:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof e' has no compatible call signatures.ts(2349)
>   index.ts(1, 1): Type originates at this import. A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime. Consider using a default import or import require here instead.

Comment: I can tell you why Attempt #2 didn't work: You asked for a module namespace object, then tried to run it as a function.

Comment: Looks like `@types/express` is missing the fact that Express provides a default export that's a function. (I just double-checked that it does, and that `import express from "express";` correctly retrieves it in JavaScript code with `--experimental-modules` enabled.) So definitely a types thing (as the error suggests). Looking in `node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts`, I see that it at least *tries* to define an export for the express function: "Creates an Express application. The express() function is a top-level function exported by the express module."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Doing a forced cast to a Function works: `const app = (express as unknown as Function)();`. It's certainly an ugly hack, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actually, that does not work... at runtime we get 'express is not a function' even though we imported it with `import * as express from 'express'`.

Comment: It should be `import express from 'express';` The `*` version imports a module namespace object, not the default export (see comments above).

Comment: (Speaking of hacks: `import * as mno from 'express'; const express = mno.default as unknown as Function;`) But the real solution (which sadly I can't help with) is to sort out the types in `@types/express/index.d.ts` and/or TypeScript's use of them.

Comment: Sorting out the types would be a worthwhile pull request. I can add that to my "maybe someday" list of things to do.

Comment: tsc with express types version 4.16.1 is not complaining about _import express, { Request, Response, Application } from 'express';_

Comment: @joseph-climber Have you also enabled `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` in the tsconfig.json file?

Comment: I wasn't even aware of it :-). It was commented out but defaulting to true as _esModuleInterop_ was set true and _target_ was _es5_ [I think](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). Actually is the _allowSyntheticDefaultImport_ option that makes the compiler stopping complaining about modules that don't have default exports but _esModuleInterop_ is also needed because it uses the helper  `__importDefault` in the generated code and the helper wraps a modulewithoutdefault as an object **{ 'default': modulewithoutdefault }** so things don't blow up in run time.

Comment: @joseph-climber Good to know. I have tended to disable `allowSyntheticDefaultImport` because it has lead to runtime troubles when compiling with Babel and testing with Jest. Maybe some other incantation of configuration options can make it work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

TypeScript has [special import syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) to deal with modules that export functions or some other custom objects as a whole (not as default export):

```
import { Request, Response, Application } from 'express';
import express = require('express');

var app: Application = express();

app.get('/', function (req: Request, res: Response) {
  res.send('Hello World')
});

app.listen(3000);
```

---

Alternatively you can use TypeScript compiler options to alter imported module so that they have default export:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
  }
}
```

and import using this default import:

```
import express from 'express' 
var app = express();
```

Comment: That's useful. In our case, though, we are targeting ECMAScript modules and see this error message: 'Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules...'

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I'm afraid that using bare `require()` is the best way to go for you. Alternatively, if you are using webpack or babel you could preprocess module `express` to "wrap" it in the default export but it's probably too much of a hassle and it might mess the types.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Are you sure you want to target ECMAScript modules in you server-side code? Node uses commonjs. You probably bundle all modules before running them with node, so it doesn't matter, but then again, why use some specific kind of modules other than native nodejs modules? Why fit round peg in square hole if you are going to pour concrete over the whole thing in the end?

Comment: That's a terrific point about using `commonjs` on the server side. I went ahead and tried that. Since we are using `babel/plugin-transform-typescript` to transpile instead of using `tsc`, there is a new error, because the babel build system does not allow `import =` to work. We could set `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports`, but that (used to) have some edge cases we want to avoid.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Yes. That's another solution. I updated my answer. I'm afraid that `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `esModuleInterop` is the right way to go for you if you are using `babel/plugin-transform-typescript`. I don't think you should be afraid of edge cases (anymore?) because what those switches do seems pretty straightforward. Just some equivalent of adding `module.exports.__default__ = module.exports` at the end of the module you are importing.

Comment: The combination of using `commonjs` and setting `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `esModuleInterop` both to `true` appears to work.

Comment: FYI, the "Alternatively..." ("allowSyntheticDefaultImports") solution doesn't work with tsc and without babel...
`error TS2724: '"express"' has no exported member named 'express'. Did you mean 'Express'?`

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to import express on a plain js project with:

```js
import express from 'express';
```

It is possible to do it aswell:

1. Set the key-value pair:

```json
"type": "module",
```

in your `package.json` file

2. Run your application with the command

```
node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node index.js
```

Answer (score -1):

Mine was giving the same error, maybe because of the version used, I decided::

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
```

e no package.json: "node index.js"